# Migrating oracle 11g to oracle 21c, ORA-00979: not a group by expression

Tags: oracle, group-by, oracle11g

I encountered an ORA-00979 error during the migration from oracle11.1 to oracle21. The following is a SQL example

```
select
     count(*)
from
     (
         select
             col_3
         from
             test_table
         where
             col_2 = '0'
         group by
             col_1
     );
```

I checked the documentation for this error, https://docs.oracle.com/en/error-help/db/ora-00979/, and learned from here that I can fix the error by changing col_3 after select to col_1, for example so

```
select
     count(*)
from
     (
         select
             col_1
         from
             test_table
         where
             col_2 = '0'
         group by
             col_1
     );
```

I tried to use ***explain plan for*** to view the execution plan of this SQL in oracle11.1 and oracle21, but oracle21 will prompt an ORA-00979 error, and my attempt failed.

So my question is, why does this SQL error not occur in oracle11.1, but does it occur in oracle21?

This is the execution plan in oracle11.1

```
Plan hash value: 129683286
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |            |     1 |       |     689  (1)| 00:00:09 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE      |            |     1 |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW               | VM_NWVW_0  |     992 |       |     689  (1)| 00:00:09 |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY     |            |     992 |    8928 |     689  (1)| 00:00:09 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST_TABLE |     27591 |    242K |     686   (1)| 00:00:09 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - SEL$DD8D4BD4
   2 - SEL$3DD9CB74 / VM_NWVW_0@SEL$DD8D4BD4
   3 - SEL$3DD9CB74
   4 - SEL$3DD9CB74 / TEST_TABLE@SEL$2
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   4 - filter("COL_2"='0')
 
Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - (#keys=0) COUNT(*)[22]
   3 - (#keys=1) "COL_1"[VARCHAR2,10]
   4 - "COL_1"[VARCHAR2,10]
```

Comment: The error does occur in [Oracle 11g](https://dbfiddle.uk/U6cP7agR), [Oracle 18](https://dbfiddle.uk/dJXsBW1e), [Oracle 21](https://dbfiddle.uk/tTvoIFsx) and [Oracle 23](https://dbfiddle.uk/-6a551x-). If you think that it does not appear in Oracle 11g then please provide a [MRE] where it does not.

Comment: @MT0  Sorry, I didn't describe it clearly. The version of oracle11g is ***11.1.0.7***. I don't have an 11gR2 environment here, so I haven't tried it to see if it runs normally. Does this website have a test environment for version 11.1?

Comment: The original query is not valid in all versions of Oracle, because it had never allowed `group by` clause to reference an alias or position or perform any "smart" aggregation. See [`select_list` restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2080424) that says: *If you also specify a group_by_clause in this statement, then this select list can contain only the following types of expressions: 1) Constants
2) Aggregate functions and the functions USER, UID, and SYSDATE
3) Expressions identical to those in the group_by_clause

Comment: @astentx The Oracle 11.1 documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55176) (but that part of the documentation appears to be identical).

Comment: @astentx  Yes, the document says that it cannot be used in this way, but the actual running result is not like this. When executing this sql in oracle11.1, I feel like it automatically appends a count() to col_3.

Comment: @MT0 As I can find it is the same since [version 7](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/dcommon/oin/indexj.htm)

Comment: @kldd Please run `explain plan for <your query>` in your 11.1 instance and post an output for `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => '+PROJECTION +ALIAS'))`.

Comment: You might have been seeing bug 16989676  "ORA-937 is NOT generated when expected" in 11g - it's shown for 11gR2 but unclear if it affected 11gR1 too. It's kind of irrelevant though, the query *should* error, so you need to fix it. (Not sure why you have the subquery though, you could `count(distinct col1) from test_table where...`)

Comment: @astentx  Hello, I have submitted the execution plan to the question

Comment: @AlexPoole Seems that Oracle optimizes the query and does group count eliminating the expression in a subquery which is not requested by the upstream operations: it [works well](https://dbfiddle.uk/qW5xA98I) for deliberately wrong but valid expressions (like `1/0`), and accidentally does the same for syntactically incorrect expressions (that is a bug - it should enforce syntax check). However suggested alternative query doesn't handle nulls: `col1` should be wrapped with some injective function that maps `null` to not null, e.g. undocumented internally used `sys_op_map_nonnull` or `dump`

Comment: @astentx - yes, agree about the nulls, my bad. Good explanation of what it seems to be doing. May or may not be the bug I referenced, nobut t sure it matters which bug is causing the incorrect behaviour in 11g as the query has to be corrected anyway, so it's only of historical interest really.

Comment: @astentx  so is this a bug in oracle11.1? Wrong optimization behavior allows the sql that should be wrong to execute normally